# Delphi set to read only files from folder and subfolders

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I put the files from a specific folder and subfolders to read only in delphi?
I know that I can put the folder with FileSetAttr to read only but is there a way to put the files from the folder and subfolders ?

Thanks

Comment: Call the `FileSetAttr` function for each file you find in a folder and its subfolders. For that search use `FindFirst`, `FindNext`.

Comment: @TLama: this belongs as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 5):

You need to iterate over all the files in a directory, and recursively over all the sub-directories. You can use this function to do that:

```
type
  TFileEnumerationCallback = procedure(const Name: string);

procedure EnumerateFiles(const Name: string; 
  const Callback: TFileEnumerationCallback);
var
  F: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(Name + '\*', faAnyFile, F) = 0 then begin
    try
      repeat
        if (F.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) then begin
          if (F.Name <> '.') and (F.Name <> '..') then begin
            EnumerateFiles(Name + '\' + F.Name, Callback);
          end;
        end else begin
          Callback(Name + '\' + F.Name);
        end;
      until FindNext(F) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(F);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This is a general purpose routine. You can supply a callback procedure that will be called with the name of each file. Inside that callback procedure do what ever you want.

Your callback procedure would look like this:

```
procedure MakeReadOnly(const Name: string);
begin
  FileSetAttr(Name, FileGetAttr(Name) or faReadOnly);
end;
```

And you'd put it together like this:

```
EnumerateFiles('C:\MyDir', MakeReadOnly);
```