# How do I run multiple commands in an if-then-else statement?

Tags: delphi, if-statement, syntax

How can I do something like this in delphi 7

```
if FileExists
    then 
        Filesetattr
        DownloadFile
    else
        Downloadfile
        Filesetattr
```

I tried with ; and it's not working.
I tried with comma (,) also not working.
So I want two or more commands to be executed in one "then statement" and two or more commands  in "else statement"

Comment: `if Condition then begin DoSome; Stuff; end else begin DoSome; OtherStuff; end;` but these are basics that you should step through when learning Pascal/Delphi.

Comment: Read this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Compound_Statements

Comment: Which book are you using to learn Delphi? It should have told you this very early on.

Comment: You should have had a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21817444/1744164) to *your* question ;o)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you want more than one line to be controlled by the if statement, surround with begin end

```
if FileExists
  then 
  begin
    Filesetattr;
    DownloadFile;
  end
  else
    begin
      Downloadfile;
      Filesetattr;
    end;
```

Comment: The layout here is quite unusual. I've never seen real code layed out quite like this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that is where I usually press Ctrl-D

Comment: Delphi does not care about the layout/formatting. The code is still 100% valid. Upvote from me.